# Does SHA-2 Hashing use a key?

Tags: security, hash, sha2

From personal knowledge I know SHA-2 hashes are irreversible and do not use a key.

But a person I know has contradicted the above very confidently, I'm now confused and couldn't  find the answer I wanted by googling.

Can anyone clear me up on this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for HMAC.

Comment: I'm not looking for anything, I need to know if SHA-2 uses a key or not.

Comment: It (SHA-2) does not use a key.

The "person you know" is wrong and may have confused hashing with HMAC (hashed message authentication code).

Answer (score 7):

Hash functions like SHA-* do not need a key, they just calculate a hash-value from any input.

There are other functions like [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), which indeed use a key, together with a hash function. So it is possible to use a key together with SHA-2, to generate a HMAC, that's what the person possibly had in mind, and what SLaks tried to point out. A HMAC has a different purpose than a hash function though.

Answer (score 4):

SHA-2, like all hash algorithms, do not use keys.

The [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of a hash function is a map from a *single* input to an output.

Comment: True, but to elaborate (since a lot of people *think* they are using a key/salt for e.g. SHA-2): All hash functions either calculate a hash-digest **without a key** or HMAC (hashed message authentication code) **with a key**. For R for example, the `openssl` package uses HMAC under the hood to support salted hashing with SHA-2.